# Unity Game BreakOut ball loses speed and direction

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just finished a BreakOut style game but there is a bug where sometimes the ball gets stuck to the edges of the map with no direction or speed as shown in the screenshot

What I see is that it happens when the ball completely loses trajectory or speed, but could not solve the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atc4U.png)

my code

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;
    Vector2 moveDirection;
    Vector2 currentVelocity;
     float velocity=10;
    //GameManager gameManager;
    Transform paddle;
    [SerializeField] AudioController audioController;
    [SerializeField] AudioClip bounceSfx;
    [SerializeField] AudioClip dieSfx;
    public bool superBall;
    [SerializeField] float superBallTime=10;
    [SerializeField]float yMinSpeed = 10;
    [SerializeField]TrailRenderer trailRenderer;

    public bool SuperBall
    {
        get=> superBall;
        set{
            superBall=value;
            if(superBall)
                StartCoroutine(ResetSuperBall());
        }
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        //rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        //rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up*velocity*Time.deltaTime;
        GameManager.Instance = FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();
        paddle = transform.parent;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        currentVelocity = rigidbody2D.velocity;
        if (Mathf.Abs(currentVelocity.y) < 3 && Mathf.Abs(currentVelocity.y) < 3 && GameManager.Instance.ballOnGame)
        {
            velocity = 10;
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up * velocity ;
        }
        if (Mathf.Abs(currentVelocity.y) + Mathf.Abs(currentVelocity.y) < 10 && GameManager.Instance.ballOnGame)
        {
            velocity = 10;
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up * velocity ;
        }
        if  (velocity <10 && GameManager.Instance.ballOnGame)
        {
            velocity = 10;
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up * velocity ;
        }

        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && GameManager.Instance.ballOnGame == false)||(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && GameManager.Instance.ballOnGame == false))
        {
            rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up * velocity ;
            transform.parent = null;
            GameManager.Instance.ballOnGame = true;
            rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
            rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector3(velocity, velocity, 0));
            if (!GameManager.Instance.GameStarted)
            {
                GameManager.Instance.GameStarted = true;

            }
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.transform.CompareTag("Brick") && superBall)
        {
            rigidbody2D.velocity = currentVelocity;
            return;
        }
        moveDirection=Vector2.Reflect(currentVelocity,collision.GetContact(0).normal);
        if (Mathf.Abs(moveDirection.y) < yMinSpeed)
        {
            //permitir velocidad minima
            moveDirection.y = yMinSpeed*Mathf.Sign(moveDirection.y);
        }
        rigidbody2D.velocity=moveDirection;

        audioController.PlaySfx(bounceSfx);

        if (collision.transform.CompareTag("BottomLimit"))
        {
            if(GameManager.Instance != null)
            {
                GameManager.Instance.PlayerLives--;
                audioController.PlayDie(dieSfx);
                if (GameManager.Instance.PlayerLives > 0)
                {
                    rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                    transform.SetParent(paddle);
                    transform.localPosition = new Vector2(0, 0.65f);
                    GameManager.Instance.ballOnGame = false;
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    IEnumerator ResetSuperBall()
    {
        trailRenderer.enabled = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(superBallTime);
        trailRenderer.enabled = false;
        GameManager.Instance.powerIsActive = false;
        superBall = false;

    }

}
```

Comment: SO is an **English-only** site - please [respect the rules of the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/205114), and either translate your question (including title!) into English, or else post it on [es.so]

Comment: You shouldn’t be setting velocity. You should be adding force and with the correct physics settings ok the ball. All should be ok

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue with Rigidbodies at low velocities. The physics engine implements a [Physics2D.velocityThreshold](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D-velocityThreshold.html) that is designed to dampen slow bounces and calm down a pile of Rigidbodies.

The default value for velocityThreshold is 1, meaning that the x or y component of the velocity that is slower will be floored to 0.

To resolve this issue you can simply lower the value to 0.001. You can do it in the Physcs2d tab located at Edit->ProjectSettings->Physics2d

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work, the ball stays stopped in consecutive collisions

Comment: @Gameraloned try to describe what happens before the ball gets stuck. If you can provide a video of this happening it would be extremely helpful.
I've examined the code again and think that the instances where you set the velocity to `rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.up * velocity ;` are to blame. Doing this operation completely kills all sideways momentum and ignores the direction of movement. 
Some of the if conditions are strange. Perhaps you can add a few comments to clarify.